# pip install colored getting error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'

Tags: python

```
Collecting colored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/14/e9c100eaa9dec369bfbf5bde3dbba93da8d2b107de9a7e49a781ba22140c/colored-1.3.9.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/jt/259zbp9j119b1r9xwl0mn87w2zc2kn/T/pip-install-by7czofn/colored/setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        long_description=open("README.rst").read()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jt/259zbp9j119b1r9xwl0mn87w2zc2kn/T/pip-install-by7czofn/colored/

Error reported on - https://gitlab.com/dslackw/colored/issues/12
```

Solution for now - download source
comment out following line from setup.py

```
#    long_description=open("README.rst").read()
```

do pip install colored - this works

Answer (score 0):

Solution for now - download source comment out following line from setup.py
long_description=open("README.rst").read()

> do pip install colored - this works